# In Python, how do I check if a drive exists w/o throwing an error for removable drives?

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, path, disk

Here's what I have so far:

```
import os.path as op
for d in map(chr, range(98, 123)): #drives b-z
    if not op.isdir(d + ':/'): continue
```

The problem is that it pops up a "No Disk" error box in Windows:

> maya.exe - No Disk: There is no disk in
>   the drive. Please insert a disk into
>   drive \Device\Harddisk1\DR1 [Cancel, Try Again, Continue]

I can't catch the exception because it doesn't actually throw a Python error.

Apparently, this only happens on removable drives where there is a letter assigned, but no drive inserted.

Is there a way to get around this issue without specifically telling the script which drives to skip?

In my scenario, I'm at the school labs where the drive letters change depending on which lab computer I'm at. Also, I have zero security privileges to access disk management.

Comment: By the way, cleaner to avoid map: `[chr(c) for c in xrange(98, 123)]`.  It's also arguably clearer to say xrange(ord('b'), ord('z'))`.  Also, don't skip "A"; nothing says it has to be a floppy drive.  I always disable the unused floppy controller, which frees up A:.

Comment: Great tip! I implemented it just now with the ord() method you described. Works great!

Comment: I just noticed I have to put `ord('z') + 1` to get this going all the way to *z* though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) package to access the [`GetLogicalDrives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  This does not require external libraries such as pywin32, so it's portable, although it is a little clunkier to work with.  For example:

```
import ctypes
import itertools
import os
import string
import platform

def get_available_drives():
    if 'Windows' not in platform.system():
        return []
    drive_bitmask = ctypes.cdll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    return list(itertools.compress(string.ascii_uppercase,
               map(lambda x:ord(x) - ord('0'), bin(drive_bitmask)[:1:-1])))
```

`itertools.compress` was added in Python 2.7 and 3.1; if you need to support <2.7 or <3.1, here's an implementation of that function:

```
def compress(data, selectors):
    for d, s in zip(data, selectors):
        if s:
            yield d
```

Comment: ah, you're a saint! don't forget to `import platform` though. also, it's still returning removable drives for which there is no drive inserted. that's actually the problem here is that i can't detect if the drive has a disk loaded or not w/o an error of some kind.

Comment: Update—Spring semester started this week and I had a chance to test this at school. Everything works well without a hiccup, but I need to try on a couple more machines before I see if it truly works w/o the pop-up.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way that works both on Windows and Linux, for both Python 2 and 3:

```
import platform,os
def hasdrive(letter):
    return "Windows" in platform.system() and os.system("vol %s: 2>nul>nul" % (letter)) == 0
```

Comment: Ummm... I don't see anything to do with linux there.

Comment: nonetheless, this is actually extremely helpful for my needs. do you happen to know of a way to suppress the command shell popping up?

Comment: @sfjedi: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188326/in-python-how-do-i-check-if-a-drive-exists-w-o-throwing-an-error-for-removable-d/4790310#4790310) for a way to do this without a command shell popping up.

Comment: Matt Joiner: the function hasdrive works on Linux too (returns False, as Linux doesn't have drive letters)

Comment: I was hoping for some info on what "os.system("vol %s: 2>nul>nul" % (letter)) == 0" actually does. I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Dylan, `vol` is a Windows command. `os.system` in combination with `2>nul>nul` runs the command in a silent way, where only the return code is used. If the return code is 0 (`== 0`) then it worked out. `%s` is replaced with the drive letter, so that for instance `vol c:` is being run. The idea is to check if this returns an error or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the [win32file](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file.html) module, you can call [GetLogicalDrives()](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file__GetLogicalDrives_meth.html):

```
def does_drive_exist(letter):
    import win32file
    return (win32file.GetLogicalDrives() >> (ord(letter.upper()) - 65) & 1) != 0
```

Comment: I like this approach; though, I'm looking for a cross-platform way of doing it, because my script will potentially be run on Maya via Windows/Mac/Linux.

Comment: @sfjedi, I'm curious to know how Maya emulates drive letters on Linux :)

Comment: Good call. I've never developed anything for Linux yet, but I just don't feel comfortable going down a road that's specific to Windows. I know that Maya runs on Linux though, which is why I'm relatively concerned. You bring up a good point though. I need to think more about the directory structure on Linux as well. Actually, I'm specifically trying to identify any flash drives that are plugged in with a "school" folder on the root. That's the actual purpose of this script.

Comment: BTW, I like how you go above and beyond to answer the real question.

Comment: this will not work in all OS of different platform

Comment: @TheEasyLearnAcademy, the question is tagged `[windows]`, so I fail to understand what the problem is. For what it's worth, the accepted answer also targets Windows only.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os 
def IsDriveExists(drive):
    return os.path.exists(drive + ':\\')
    
print(IsDriveExists('c')) 
print(IsDriveExists('d'))
print(IsDriveExists('e'))
print(IsDriveExists('x'))
print(IsDriveExists('v'))
```

this works in any os

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks! So much more pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the error popup, you need to set the `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` Windows error flag using pywin:

```
old_mode = win32api.SetErrorMode(0)
SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 1 # not provided by PyWin, last I checked
win32api.SetErrorMode(old_mode & 1)
```

This tells Win32 not to show the retry dialog; when an error happens, it's returned to the application immediately.

Note that this is what Python calls are *supposed* to do.  In principle, Python should be setting this flag for you.  Unfortunately, since Python may be embedded in another program, it can't change process-wide flags like that, and Win32 has no way to specify this flag in a way that only affects Python and not the rest of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, though I'm testing this on Windows 7, I'm trying to make this script cross-platform. Plus, it looks like the win32api needs a different build depending on what kind of processor you have and I'd have to install every single one of these builds just to make this compatible. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As long as a little parsing is acceptable, this is one way to do it without installing win32api and without iterating through all possible drive letters.

```
from subprocess import check_output
def getDriveLetters():
    args = [
        'wmic',
        'logicaldisk',
        'get',
        'caption,description,providername',
        '/format:csv'
    ]
    output = check_output(args)
    results = list()
    for line in  output.split('\n'):
        if line:
            lineSplit = line.split(',')
            if len(lineSplit) == 4 and lineSplit[1][1] == ':':
                results.append(lineSplit[1][0])
    return results
```

You could also parse for specific drive types, such as "Network Connection" to get a list of all network mounted drive letters by adding `and lineSplit[2] == 'Network Connection'` for example.

Alternatively, rather than returning a list, you could return a dictionary, where keys are drive letters and values are unc paths (`lineSplit[3]`). Or whatever other info you want to pull from `wmic`. To see more options: `wmic logicaldisk get /?`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

possible_drives_list = [chr(97 + num).upper() for num in range(26)]

for drive in possible_drives_list:
    print(drive + ' exists :' + str(os.path.exists(drive + ':\\')))
```